# IOUtils.toByteArray() OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

i try to compress large video file with more than 100Mb in size.

```
public static void compress(File input, File output) throws    IOException {
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
        byte[] bFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
        GZIPOutputStream gzipStream = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
        try {
            gzipStream.write(bFile);
            // IOUtils.copy(fis, gzipStream);
        } finally {
            gzipStream.close();
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        }           
    }
```

every time i got outofmemoryerror.

Comment: So what's your question? I think it's rather normal to get OOM when loading 100 MB into memory on a mobile platform. Don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

You should copy the data progressively and you won't run out of memory.

```
public static void compress(File input, File output) throws IOException {
    try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream(input);
        OutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output))) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
        for(int len; (len = in.read(bytes)) > 0; )
            out.write(bytes, 0, len);
    }           
}
```

This will use about 4 KB as a buffer at once, regardless of the size of the file. (I suspect the GZIP uses about the same to do it's work)

Comment: ok, i got Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7 because i use java 1.6. and if i switch to java 1.7 i got this Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
```

which will handle the byte buffers itself. You don't need to explicitly create a byte[] because in case of large size you are loading large size byte array in memory by using :

`IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);` // this will load entire byte array into memory.